# Tag values depending on multiple column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that I have this minimal DataFrame to represent my needs:

```
    Tag   Year   Month   Snowed 
0    0    2001    Jan     True
1    0    2001    Feb     False 
2    0    2001    Mar     True
3    0    2002    Jan     True
4    0    2002    Feb     True
5    0    2002    Mar     False
```

How could I fill the Tag column such that, for each year, it is tagged as BAD if snowed in both Jan&Feb or GOOD otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `transform`, `all`, and `ffill`:

```
df['Tage']=df.loc[df.Month.isin(['Jan','Feb'])].groupby('Year')['Snowed'].transform('all').map({False:'Good',True:'Bad'})
df.ffill(inplace=True)
df
Out[262]: 
   Tag  Year Month  Snowed  Tage
0    0  2001   Jan    True  Good
1    0  2001   Feb   False  Good
2    0  2001   Mar    True  Good
3    0  2002   Jan    True   Bad
4    0  2002   Feb    True   Bad
5    0  2002   Mar   False   Bad
```

---

```
s=df.loc[df.Month.isin(['Jan','Feb'])].groupby('Year')['Snowed'].agg('all').map({False:'Good',True:'Bad'})
```

Then `map` back

```
df['Tage']=df.Year.map(s)
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that it requires the DataFrame to be sorted by year and month number, otherwise `ffill` does not populate the `Tag` field correctly. In the given example it is, of course, sorted, so no problem

Comment: If I understand, the proposed solution checks that 'all' filtered values are True or False. How would it be to check if they are NaN or not? In the second step, the solution for this filtered rows is extended. As pointed out, the .ffill does not seem to be a safe approach for arbitrary month selections. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above answer, this also works. This code might be less confusing though.

Since we don't care about the data in March as per your question:
`df = df[(df.Month != 'Mar')]`

```
def True_Or_Not(df):
    Result = df['Snowed'].all(axis=None) == True
    df['Result'] = Result
    return df
```

Groupby Year and aggregate month column to determine whether all values are true

```
df  = df.groupby(['Year']).apply(lambda df: True_Or_Not(df)).reset_index().drop(columns = ['index'])
df['Tag'] = ['Good' if i== False else 'Bad' for i in df.Result.tolist()]
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Tag     Year    Month   Snowed  Result
0   Good    2001    Jan    True     False
1   Good    2001    Feb    False    False
2   Bad     2002    Jan    True     True
3   Bad     2002    Feb    True     True
```